# Get the amount of days in a month - mdx

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, mdx, cube

In TSQL I can do this to get the amount of days in some month:

```
declare @date as datetime
set @date = '2015-02-06'
select datediff(day, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date),
              dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1-day(@date), @date)))
```

How can I get the same functionality in MDX?
P.S. I need the result to be an int.

Comment: create a date dimension.

Comment: I have one, but it doesn't have the amount of days in a month in it.

Comment: @PaulKar. it is just an extra column in your dimension that uses the sql you already have. This could then be a property of each date in your cube - much simpler, and efficient, than the `mdx` solutions presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a year-month-date hierarchy in place, it could be done in the below fashion:

```
WITH MEMBER NumOfDaysInMonth AS
DateDiff(       
            "d",
             HEAD(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Calendar Date].CURRENTMEMBER, 1)).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION, //Gets the first date of the month
             TAIL(DESCENDANTS([Date].[Calendar Date].CURRENTMEMBER, 1)).ITEM(0).MEMBER_CAPTION  //Gets the last date of the month
        ) + 1
```

You just need to to pass the month's value in the slicer. The calculated member will do the rest.

```
SELECT NumOfMonths ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE ([Date].[Calendar Date].[Month].&[Dec-2015])
```

Comment: some cube designers to not include future date members in their cubes. Our cubes currently contain only upto the 9th Of June. Your method would not work in this context.

Comment: My cube has future dates inside DIM.Date, but I think adding a column would be simpler. If I wouldn't do that, I would use this answer since it looks simpler.

Comment: Can you explain what is the select doing here? Is it selecting Dec 2015? I would like it to be dynamic and not for a specific month.

Comment: Yep it is doing that. If you wanted the month to be dynamic, you would have to use `StrToSet` function and pass the parameter in the `WHERE` clause instead of `[Date].[Calendar Date].[Month].&[Dec-2015]`

Comment: How would I do that if I would like to create a member and not slice by year/month?

Comment: @PaulKar. both of our solutions use the function `.CURRENTMEMBER`. This function uses the member of the date dimension that is within the current context. If no member is within context then these solutions return nothing, but why would I want to know the number of days in September but not be interested in September - this seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method we use:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [MEASURES].[NumOfDaysInMonth] AS 
    IIF
    (
      VBA!Isdate([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name)
     ,Datepart
      ("D"
       ,
          Dateadd
          ("M"
           ,1
           ,Cdate
            (
                Cstr(VBA!Month([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name)) + "-01-"
              + 
                Cstr(VBA!Year([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name))
            )
          )
        - 1
      )
     ,''
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[MEASURES].[NumOfDaysInMonth]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Date].[Calendar].[All]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2005]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Semester].&[2008]&[2]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[3]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20060214]
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[11]
    } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The above returns the following:

[image]